# Menu filtered according to specific permissions

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, menu, html-lists

I want to create a menu which contains all my services according to permissions. And any new service added automatically to this menu . I use a table (`Runat="server"`) in my div and dynamically create new `td` at runtime with the new service according to the permission.

I want to ask if there are any ideas to do this more perfectly and good from UI perspective.

Comment: What you want to say with "new service", a new link to a new page added?

Comment: What you can do is use a method, for exemple, that will use Reflection to inspect you assembly and find your pages aspx, and for each page create the html, i do the same thing with a asp.net mvc project. excactly the same thing. Unfortunately i'm leaving of my job now, but tomorrow, if anyone help you, we can think together and create a solution to a web forms project. Before of all, post how you are organizing your aspx pages (folders and etc..) and how you are giving permissions (with role provider and authorization attribute?)

Answer (score 0):

As I undrestood right, it would be better to create client-side object which will build your menu. Input parameter for this object is a JSON with your data. If you need to make any modifications with your GUI, you will change only js/css objects without rebuilding all project.

I hope it will also helps you

[Getting The List Of All Pages In The Application.](http://vaultofthoughts.net/GettingTheListOfAllPagesInTheApplication.aspx)

Please, clarify your issue if my answer isn't right.